# ReactJS:call child method from another child component?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

i using ReactJS 16.12 and have three  components. 1)Parent   2)History    3)SvgViewer .  i want call a function belongs to History component(a child component) from SvgViewer functional component(another child component).
thanks for solutions...

this is my code:

1)Parent Component:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import History from "./history";
import SvgViewer from "./svg-viewer";

class UnitMonitor extends PureComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.History = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Row type="flex" className="">
        <Col span={25}>
          <History ref={this.History} />
          <SvgViewer
            svgFilePath={this.state.svgFilePath}
            nodesData={this.state.nodes}
          />
        </Col>
      </Row>
    );
  }
}
export default UnitMonitor;
```

2)History:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import {Modal } from "antd";

class History extends Component {
  state = {
    modalVisible: false,
    tableData: [{}]
  };

  //i need call this method //
  modalHistoryShow = nodeId => {
    axios.get("api/tag-values/get-history/" + nodeId).then(response => {
      this.setState({ tableData: response.data });
      console.log(this.state.tableData);
    });
    this.setState({ modalVisible: true });
  };

render(){
    return (
      <Modal
        visible={this.state.modalVisible}
        name="modalHistory"
        footer={[null]}
        width={"1000px"}
      >
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}

export default History;
```

3)SvgViewer:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";

const SvgViewer = ({ nodesData, svgFilePath }) => {
  const [svgContainer, setSvgContainer] = useState(undefined);

  const showNodesOnSvg = nodes => {
    //this.setState({ objectLoading: false });
    //let nodesData = UnitMonitor.state.nodes;
    let svgDoc = svgContainer.contentDocument;
    let gTags = svgDoc.querySelectorAll("svg > g");
    let container = null;
    if (gTags.length > 1) container = svgDoc.querySelector("g:nth-of-type(2)");
    else container = svgDoc.querySelector("g:nth-of-type(1)");
    let node = d3.select(container);
    nodesData.forEach(nodeData => {
      node
        .append("text")
        .attr("id", "node" + nodeData["id"])
        .attr("fill", "white")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("x", nodeData["positionX"])
        .attr("y", nodeData["positionY"])
        .attr("class", "clickable-node")
        .style("font-size", "8px")
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .style("cursor", "pointer")
        .style("display", "inline-block")
        .on("click", function() {
          clickHandler(nodeData["id"]);
        })
        .text("N/A" + " " + nodeData["symbol"]);
      let nodeCreated = d3.select(
        svgDoc.getElementById("node" + nodeData["id"])
      );
      nodeCreated
        .append("title")
        .attr("id", "title" + nodeData["id"])
        .text(" " + nodeData["tagCode"]);
    });
  };
  const clickHandler = nodeID => {
     History.ModalHistoryShow(nodeID); // i need call ModalHistoryShow() this way
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const svg = document.querySelector("#svgobject");
    setSvgContainer(svg);
    svg.onload = () => {
      if (nodesData != null) {
        showNodesOnSvg();
      }
    };
  });

  return (
    <div className="unit-schema-container1" key={svgFilePath}>
      <object id="svgobject" type="image/svg+xml" data={svgFilePath}></object>
    </div>
  );
};
export default SvgViewer;
```

Comment: You could pass `nodeId` to the `History` component and call the function from there when `nodeId` is updated.

Comment: @Superblar, i`m newbie in react.js. please give me a sample code

Answer (score 0):

May be my answer is most generic but I think best option in my view would be one of the 2 things below:-

1. Pass nodeId to history component and use useEffect Hook in History component and use nodeId as dependency so that everytime node Id changes your code in useEffect will execute. e.g-

```
useEffect(()=>{
     // your logic to execute goes here
     },[nodeId])
```

2. Create a custom hook which have you code from history component extracted out and same hook then can be called out from anywhere your code so it will make your code reusable.